# Bintray upload failing, unable to find class R

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew, bintray, jcenter

I have made an android library by following [this](http://blogs.quovantis.com/how-to-publish-android-library-on-bintrayjcenter/). Everything worked perfectly fine and I was able to upload my library to jcenter, also my library internally uses one java jar as dependecy.

Now I have made some improvements and wants to update my library but when I run the command

```
gradlew clean build bintrayUpload
```

it fails at

> `Task :worldlineipg:javadoc`(that's my library module)

and throws below error's

- Multiple `package com.awl.xxxxx` does not exist issues (That's all in my JAR)
- `cannot find symbol import com.worldline.in.ipg.R`;
- cannot find symbol public class PaymentStandard extends `AppCompatActivity`

But if I directly run app on my device from android studio Run(Shift+F10) all module build's fine and Run perfectly.

Can anyone guide me what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the error's worked for me.

Even though there were multiple error's on the console yet the module was uploaded successfully